# How can I make a descendent element of a flexbox item scrollable?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using a flexbox layout with the goal of expanding the last item to fit the available screen space. When that item is too large, I would like to scroll one of the descendant elements. However, I'm unable to get scrolling working as desired.

Example layout:

```js
var node = document.getElementById("table-body");
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  node.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
#grid-selected-container {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
#grid-available-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div id="grid-selected-container">
    <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-selected">
      <tr>
        <td>placeholder</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="button-render" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">placeholder</button>
  <div id="grid-available-container">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="fixed-head">
        <table width="100%" class="display">
          <thead>
            <th>header</th>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-body">
        <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-available">
          <tbody id="table-body">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can scroll the entire flex item:

```js
var node = document.getElementById("table-body");
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  node.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
#grid-selected-container {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
#grid-available-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div id="grid-selected-container">
    <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-selected">
      <tr>
        <td>placeholder</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="button-render" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">placeholder</button>
  <div id="grid-available-container">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="fixed-head">
        <table width="100%" class="display">
          <thead>
            <th>header</th>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-body">
        <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-available">
          <tbody id="table-body">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't want to scroll the *entire* flex item. I want to scroll the table body, i.e. the `scroll-body` div. `fixed-head`, which contains the table header amongst other things, should not scroll out of view. This is where I run into issues:

```js
var node = document.getElementById("table-body");
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  node.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
#grid-selected-container {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
#grid-available-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll-body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div id="grid-selected-container">
    <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-selected">
      <tr>
        <td>placeholder</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="button-render" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">placeholder</button>
  <div id="grid-available-container">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="fixed-head">
        <table width="100%" class="display">
          <thead>
            <th>header</th>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-body">
        <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-available">
          <tbody id="table-body">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To allow scrolling (`overflow: auto`) at all, I need to set a fixed height on the parents - apparently the flexbox isn't enough. But when I set a fixed height of `100%`, the flex item expands to the size of the entire screen, instead of shrinking. I want the main body to remain unscrollable, so the flex item *should* shrink.

How can I make the `scroll-body` div scroll while preventing scrolling elsewhere?

---

The real table is rendered using the jQuery DataTables plugin - the code in this question is merely an attempt to replicate the structure and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on some of the other similar questions, it seems that something with nested flexboxes might be the answer, but I'm unable to get a working example... they all devolve into one of the three forms of incorrect scrolling already shown.

Comment: @humble.rumble Any chance you could provide a full example? I've tried setting `.scroll-body` as `position:absolute;`, and both `.scroll-body > table` as the inner element and inserting an empty inner element after the table. Both produce the full-body scrolling as in my first example. Either I'm misunderstanding your instructions, or they don't work.

Comment: @humble.rumble Unfortunately, that becomes more like my second case - the header shouldn't scroll. And I can't guarantee an exact height for the button, table header, other elements, etc. - which means the hardcoded `70%` would not work. Probably could measure the size with JS, but I'd like to keep the layout in CSS if possible. I'm working with your previous suggestion of an absolute position inner div, and I'm getting *close* but not quite.

Comment: @humble.rumble Got it! Thanks for the absolute positioning tip. (But the outer container is `relative`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: as of June 2015, this works on Firefox and IE (!) but fails on Chrome. Possibly [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341310) Chrome flexbox bug.

A combination of nested flex layouts and the absolute positioned scrollable box trick humble.rumble suggested:

```js
var node = document.getElementById("table-body");
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  node.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
#grid-selected-container {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
#grid-available-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll-body tbody {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div id="grid-selected-container">
    <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-selected">
      <tr>
        <td>placeholder</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="button-render" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">placeholder</button>
  <div id="grid-available-container">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
      <div class="fixed-head">
        <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-available">
          <thead>
            <th>header</th>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-body">
        <table width="100%" class="display" id="grid-available">
          <tbody id="table-body">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are three layers. First, a flex layout (`.scroll-wrapper`) with the table header and body as its children. The flex layout will take care of letting the fixed header take as much space as it wants, and filling the rest with the body.

Then the actual scrollable area is two block-layout divs (in this case, a div and a tbody). The first one (`.scroll-body`) is the relatively-positioned block that fills the rest of the flex, and the second level (`.scroll-body tbody`) is the absolutely-positioned block where the scrollable content goes - the absolute positioning prevents it from expanding the first level.